# statistic engine that work with heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, r, statistics, heroku

I have a heroku rails app that needs to crunch some serious numbers, and I need to use a stat library like R (worse comes to worse MatLab).

I am looking to an answer to any of these questions:

1. Are there any fully featured Statistics package GEMs that do not require a binary?
2. Is it possible to get the R binary as part of the heroku stack?
3. Are there any Statistics Cloud services out there (the only one i saw was Cloudnumbers -- but in closed Beta)

Comment: I'm working on R as a service, but need some funding: http://reniga.de/

Comment: Some of the pieces that will allow you to build R as a JSON service are Rook and rApache. Then, you only need a Ruby client.

Comment: @Jeff, Do you have anything setup -- looking for beta clients?

Comment: @Jeff, With Rook and rApache can you link to instructions to setting up a server -- ideally in a scalable cloud environment -- If you make it an answer I can select it.

Answer (score 4):

Two options as of today:

- [Jeroen Oom's OpenCPU Project](http://www.opencpu.org/)
- [Noah Lorang's rookonheroku project](https://github.com/noahhl/rookonheroku)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to check out cloudnumbers again, they're public now. I just run a few calculations and it looks quite promising up to now (especiall that they fully setup external dependencies).

Answer (score 1):

Heroku is based on Amazon's AWS EC2 Service, one possibility is to manually spin up as needed an EC2 instance with R, etc. and then use that for your number crunching.

If you want to do see if it is feasible [try this AMI](http://www.drewconway.com/zia/?p=2701), which is preconfigured with R.

Answer (score 0):

There's `statistics2`:

http://raa.ruby-lang.org/project/statistics2/

Edit: I should add that there's also an updated version on Github:

https://github.com/abscondment/statistics2

Comment: ? it looks like this only provides statistical distributions (nice, but not "a fully featured statistics package") ... ?